# How to Calculate in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I'm using crystal report using formula fields.

I have this solution:

```
SUM({@Grade} * ({@lec} + {@lab})) / SUM({@lec} + {@lab})
```

Then if I save and close there's an error says

> "A field is required here"

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

fields/formulas names should look like this:  {fieldName} or {@forulaName}.
You are missing the { }

It is easy to insert the correct names by finding and double-clicking the target field/formula in the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Sum accepts only a simple object, not an expression. 
Create a formula 3Elements: `@Grade} * ({@lec} + {@lab})`
Create a formula 2Elements: `{@lec} + {@lab}`
Create a formula: `SUM({@3Elements}) / SUM({@2Elements})`